# Trouble passing Heroku config var through Node.js to Angular CLI app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, heroku

I'm working on a project where I need to pass a stripe key as JSON in Angular.

I added the key to Heroku in Config vars and have been trying to pass that value through the Node.js backend to Angular with the process.env.STRIPE_KEY method that was stated in the Heroku tutorial. I am completely lost and am unsure if I am going at this the correct way.

Here is my node server file.

```
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const router = express.Router();


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.listen(3000, function(){});

router.all('*',function(req,res,next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");
  next();

});



router.post('/stripetestkey', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    'STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY': process.env.STRIPE_KEY
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Here is the Service provider (in app modules and injected properly)getting the key from the server

```
//service.ts

import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class KeyService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  private getError(error: Response): Observable<any>{
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server Issue');
  }

  getKey(): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/stripetestkey',{ headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.getError);
  }


}
```

And here is the code I have for opening Stripe checkout with the proper key

```
 openCheckout() {
    this.keyService.getKey().subscribe(data => this.stripeTestKey = data.STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY);
    let handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: this.stripeTestKey,
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function (token: any) {

      }
    });
    handler.open({
      name: 'XXXXXX',
      description: 'Donation',
      amount: (this.donation * 100)
    });
  }
```

I've been getting HTML back instead of JSON and am just unsure if I'm even going at this correctly. I've also tried passing JSON instead of process.env.STRIPE_KEY. Can anyone let me know what I need to do to pass a heroku config var through node.js to my angular app?

Thanks!

P.S. here is the error I am receiving ..

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.bundle.js:32 Response
vendor.bundle.js:1443 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json
```

UPDATE ** 
I changed res.send to res.json in server.js and here is the updated error I am getting.

```
keys.service.ts:11 Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /stripetestkey</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…}


core.es5.js:1084 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http.es5.js:796)
```

UPDATE #2 *******
I've changed router.post to router.get in server.js. I'm still getting the same error stated above. I tried passing the key directly as an object

```
router.get('/stripetestkey', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    'STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY': 'pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  });
});
```

and Stripe returned this error for me.

```
StripeCheckout.configure: Type mismatch for option 'key':
Looking for type 'string', but instead we found 'object'.
You can learn about the available configuration options in the Checkout docs:
```

Checking out the docs now.

**** Still Struggling here

[image]

****UPDATE (so many)
Changed http://localhost:3000/stripetestkey to https://localhost:3000/keys (also changed server side to /keys for correct routing (easier to follow).

```
OPTIONS https://localhost:3000/keys net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
scheduleTask @ zone.js:1990
webpackJsonp.585.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:384
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:274
webpackJsonp.585.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:378
webpackJsonp.585.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:209
webpackJsonp.585.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:232
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2014
send @ VM1198:3
(anonymous) @ http.es5.js:1254
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:57
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:45
MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:42
CatchOperator.call @ catch.js:79
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:42
webpackJsonp.237.NavbarComponent.openCheckout @ navbar.component.ts:74
(anonymous) @ NavbarComponent.html:40
handleEvent @ core.es5.js:11798
callWithDebugContext @ core.es5.js:13006
debugHandleEvent @ core.es5.js:12594
dispatchEvent @ core.es5.js:8773
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:9363
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.es5.js:2683
webpackJsonp.585.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:398
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:4116
webpackJsonp.585.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:397
webpackJsonp.585.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:165
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:460
keys.service.ts:11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `res.json()` instead of `res.send()`

```
router.post('/stripetestkey', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    'KeyCode': process.env.STRIPE_KEY
  });
});
```

Link to express documention on `res.json()`: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

EDIT per the 404 error you are getting:

Make sure you are requesting the same resource with the same verb (GET, POST, etc.) as your router is defining. In your case, you are defining a POST request in ExpressJS, but your client is trying to GET the request which doesn't exist per your router (`this.http.get()` in your .ts file)

Your new route will be:

```
router.get('/stripetestkey', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    'KeyCode': process.env.STRIPE_KEY
  });
});
```

UPDATE to help illustrate how to ensure `this.stripeTestKey` is set before `handler.open()`

Because `this.keyService.getKey().subscribe()` is async, handler.open() is getting called before you set the this.stripTestKey. You can do something similar to the following to fix it in your .subscribe() callback:

```
openCheckout() {
  this.keyService.getKey().subscribe(data => {
    this.stripeTestKey = data.STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY

    let handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: this.stripeTestKey,
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function (token: any) {

      }
    });
    handler.open({
      name: 'XXXXXX',
      description: 'Donation',
      amount: (this.donation * 100)
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I changed res.send to res.json but still got an error. See above for edits in error.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that you were trying to GET from the client but you're Express router is defining a POST request. Can you use router.get() instead of router.post() -- 

router.get('/stripetestkey', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    'KeyCode': process.env.STRIPE_KEY
  });
});

Comment: I changed as you stated. I'm still getting the same error. I tried passing the key directly in the object in a dev environment and got the error given by Stripe above. I may be missing something else, I'm just unsure of what that is.

Comment: If you're returning JSON, and then parsing the JSON, you need to get the appropriate key for that JSON. So if your server is returning the JSON object {"KeyCode", "value"}, the following needs to get KeyCode from the returned object: So the following `this.keyService.getKey().subscribe(data => this.stripeTestKey = data);` turns into `this.keyService.getKey().subscribe(data => this.stripeTestKey = data.KeyCode);`

Comment: Also, the errors above (`{_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /key</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 404...`) indicates you're trying to request the `/key` route which isn't the route you are sending the KeyCode in. It's `/stripetestkey` that your setting up in your router, so the client needs to request that route.

Comment: that was my mistake, I changed the url around but they were matching, I just posted the error with that path. I added data.KeyCode and still haven't had luck. I posted the error picture of everything I am seeing.

Comment: I don't know how you're running your ExpressJS server, but a `404` response just means the route isn't setup correctly. You don't need to setup a router separately (i.e. `var router = express.Router()`). Instead of setting up a separate router, just take `app` and bind your CORS middleware and `/stripetestkey` to it (so `router.all()... and router.get()...` becomes `app.all()... and app.get()...`, and you can module.exports = app instead of router. You should also wait to app.listen() after you setup your middleware and all routes.

Comment: before I change anything, check out my update, I am receiving a new error which if not promising, I will try your approach.

Comment: So I figured out the 404 error. It wasn't switching to https (changed it back), I wasn't routing correctly in the backend. I organized Express to look for routes in a routes folder and that seemed to get rid of the 404 error. Now, it still says I'm passing an object when it is expecting a string. I did add the proper data.KeyCode but it still says I'm passing an object

Comment: So it looks like you changed your browser request to use `https` from `http`, which if the page you're on is accessing the server over `http` would initiate an OPTIONS request per the CORS standard (since this would in fact be a CORS request). I doubt output you're seeing from your latest update is anything but a red herring.

Comment: Changed it back my check my last comment.

Comment: If you run `console.log(data)` after you get the data but before you send your StripeCheckout request, can you confirm what data is? What does it output to the console?

Comment: Ok, so changing this.keyService.getKey().subscribe(data => this.newKey = data.KeyCode); to this.keyService.getKey().subscribe(data => console.log(data)); is logging the correct object. When I click the button twice, the stripe key works on the second attempt, on the first attempt, it receives an object and not the key specifically. Would you know why?

Comment: Yeah, `this.keyService.getKey().subscribe(callback)` is asynchronous, so `handler.open()` will get called before you have set `this.stripeTestKey = data.STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY` the first time. You need to either call handler.open() from within the `data => this.stripeTestKey = data.STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY` arrow function, or make sure `this.stripeTestKey` is set before calling handler.open(). There are good tools (Promises) and patterns (asyncjs) to do this already, but the that's the reason why the second time (and beyond) the button is clicked, it's after this.stripeTestKey was set the first time.

Comment: How would I add handler.open() in the arrow function?

Comment: I called getKey() in ngOnInIt to bypass that issue. Now, when adding process.env.STRIPE_TEST_KEY in place of the actual key, it's returning undefined.

Comment: I updated my answer at the end to show what you could turn the arrow function into to make it work. This post is slowly creeping scope beyond what was originally asked (how to get your environment variable from an ExpressJS app to the client), so if you still have issues I would recommend opening a new question to help with Javascript async programming.